# Vundle not instaling Plugins / Ignoring

Tags: vimrc, installing, plugin-vundle

I installed Vundle via `git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`, and have my `.vimrc` as:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'



Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'vim-latex/vim-latex'




set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
```

When I hit `:PluginInstall (!)`, it shows the plugin screen but only Vundle is installed. Hitting `l` for the log gives me:

```
[2018-09-01 22:42:44]                               |
[2018-09-01 22:42:44] Plugin VundleVim/Vundle.vim   |~                                                                                                                                                              
[2018-09-01 22:42:44] $ cd '/home/name/.vim/bundle/|~                                                                                                                                                              
Vundle.vim' && git pull && git submodule update --in|~                                                                                                                                                              
it --recursive                                      |~                                                                                                                                                              
[2018-09-01 22:42:44] > Already up-to-date.         |~                                                                                                                                                              
[2018-09-01 22:42:44] >                             |~                                                                                                                                                              
[2018-09-01 22:42:44]                               |~                                                                                                                                                              
[2018-09-01 22:42:44] Helptags:                     |~                                                                                                                                                              
[2018-09-01 22:42:44] :helptags /home/name/.vim/bun|~                                                                                                                                                              
dle/Vundle.vim/doc                                  |~                                                                                                                                                              
[2018-09-01 22:42:44] Helptags: 1 plugins processed |~
```

I've checked the `.vimrc` path with `:echo $MYVIMRC` and it points to the above file. I've also tried to install plugins with the command: `vim +PluginInstall +qall`, and for a millisecond or so it flashes a screen which seems to have a red line, however I can't follow up.

Both `curl` and `git` work and are installed. How do I find out where it goes wrong? I've seen similar questions and they are not helpful. I've restarted Vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.vimrc` you're calling `vundle#begin()` twice and after the second one you're only loading the Vundle plugin. That's probably why it's ignoring the other plugins you have outside that block.

You're also missing the call to `vundle#end()` and re-enabling the filetype detection.

Take a look at [Vundle's quick start](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/blob/master/README.md#quick-start) again to see what your `.vimrc` should look like.

Comment: Thanks! I copy pasted the begining and end of the example .vimrc separately and probably failed to copy the end. What a silly mistake!